# Sending jQuery $.ajax POST requests without invoking function objects

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I'm using jQuery's $.ajax function to send some data to a web service. I have some code like this:

```
var updateModule = function (module)
{
   return $.ajax(moduleServiceUrl + "/UpdateModule/" + module.WorkflowModuleId,
   {
      type: "POST",
      data: module
   });
};
```

"module" is a JavaScript object that has some fields, and also an update function that will update the fields from some input.

The problem I am facing is that the $.ajax call is invoking the update function. I think I understand the reason for this, it is assuming that functions are getters, but it is undesirable in this case.

Is there any way to tell jQuery to ignore fields that are functions, rather than invoking them? Or should I just serialize the object to a string or data-only object myself, rather than relying on jQuery to do it?

Comment: serialize the object to JSON then send it.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I did, probably better anyway. Still curious if there is a way to tell jQuery not to invoke functions, in case I have a situation where the server doesn't accept JSON.

Comment: not that i'm aware of unfortunately, but maybe someone with some *black magic* has the solution.